Save Access token with extra Claim "assertion_details" when using Duende AccessTokenManagement
I have a .net 8 webApi used for logging in to a secure site using OpenIdConnect.
We are using Duende nuget packages to handle DPoP. This works great, but we have a workflow where we enrich the acccess token with an extra claim (RAR.
We need to use the userId from the initial login and use this value as a parameter in our backend to build the "RAR" object used to populate the extra Claim. We update our login by calling RequestRefresTokenAsync() from a httpClient.
var refreshTokenResult = await httpClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
{
    ClientCredentialStyle = ClientCredentialStyle.PostBody,
    ClientAssertion = clientAssertion, //This ClientAssertion contains the Extra Claim
    Address = _appSettings.HelseId.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = _appSettings.HelseId.ClientId,
    RefreshToken = token.RefreshToken,
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    GrantType = OidcConstants.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
    DPoPProofToken = ClientAssertionBuilder.CreateDPoPProof(_appSettings.HelseId.RsaKey, _appSettings.HelseId.TokenEndpoint, "POST", dPoPNonce: dPoPNonce, token.AccessToken)

});

My refreshTokenResult contains AccessToken with the extra claim and I can use this AccessToken to perform what needs to be done.
Unfortunately I am unable to use Duendes library that handles DPoP and automatically manages AccessTokens, handles Token expiry and refreshes etc by injecting a named HttpClient with ".AddUsesrAccessTokenHandler"
I would like to use this:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyApi")
    .AddUserAccessTokenHandler();

But, unfortunately, if I use the "MyApi" httpClient my AccessToken which is refreshed and enriched with the extra Claim will get replaced by the initial AccessToken missing the extra Claim.
How can I either update the accesstokenManagement from Duende with my new token, but preferably extendt the service to add my extra Claim? The problem is, I do not have the extra Claim untill the user is authenticated and I have read a parameter to the controller/endpoint the client request.
I have tried to implement my own IClientAssertionService and try to read the extra claim from Cookies after writing the Cookie in my Controller, but the value does not seem to be available.
// Use client assertion for automatic refresh of tokens
builder.Services.AddScoped<IClientAssertionService, ClientAssertionService>();
public Task<ClientAssertion?> GetClientAssertionAsync(string? clientName = null, TokenRequestParameters? parameters = null)
{
    var rarValue = FindCookie(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers, "rar");
            
    string assertionValue = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rarValue ))
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("GetClientAssertionAsync Create ClientAssertion with RAR");
        var hcpInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HcpInformation>(rarValue );
         assertionValue = ClientAssertionBuilder.GetClientAssertion(options.ClientId, options.RsaKey, options.Authority,hcpInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("GetClientAssertionAsync Create ClientAssertion without RAR. No Cookie found");
        
         assertionValue = ClientAssertionBuilder.GetClientAssertion(options.ClientId, options.RsaKey, options.Authority,null);
    }         
    return Task.FromResult<ClientAssertion?>(new ClientAssertion
    {
        Type = OidcConstants.ClientAssertionTypes.JwtBearer,
        Value = assertionValue
    });
}

